# React cant perform action on unmounted component due to status code check

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have been trying to setup a redirect if a query returns a 400 status {order not found} or if the query doesn't return anything. However, as soon as I add the status code check it gives this error:

Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
    in OrderTracking (created by Context.Consumer)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import TrackingRender from '../TrackingRender/TrackingRender'


export class OrderTracking extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            order: []
        }
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
        this._isMounted = true;
        const { id } = this.props.match.params
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/orders/${id}`)
        const data = await response.json()
        if (!data || response.status == 400) {
            await this.props.history.push('/orders')
        }
        this.setState({
            order: data
        })
        console.log(this.state)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                < TrackingRender order={this.state.order} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default OrderTracking
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind! Used axios and reread some documentation on the error. Here is the updated code if anybody is interested or has the same error in the future.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import TrackingRender from '../TrackingRender/TrackingRender'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';


export class OrderTracking extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            loadingData: true,
            order: []
        }
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
        this._isMounted = true;
        if (this.state.loadingData) {
            try {
                const { id } = this.props.match.params
                const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/orders/${id}`)
                const data = await response.json()
                this.setState({
                    order: data,
                    loadingData: false
                })
                console.log(this.state)
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }

        }

    }
    render() {
        if (!this.state.loadingData) {
            return (
                <div>
                    < TrackingRender order={this.state.order} />
                </div>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <Redirect to='/orders' />
            )
        }

    }
}

export default OrderTracking
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TrackingRender from '../TrackingRender/TrackingRender';

export class OrderTracking extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      order: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var _this = this;
    this._isMounted = true;
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;

    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/orders/${id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          _this.setState({
            order: data,
          });
        } else {
          if (res.status === 400) {
            this.props.history.push('/orders');
          }
        }
      })
      .then((data) => console.log('data is', data))
      .catch((error) => console.log('error is', error));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TrackingRender order={this.state.order} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default OrderTracking;
```

Comment: For some reason I am getting the error that response.json is not a function. Any idea why?